# Cannot perform segue from cell with indexPath

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to perform a segue and pass data to detailViewController from my cell when tapped. I have tried with dummy data and I can pass them to detailScreen, however I would like to pass data that are related to cells.When I tapped a cell I get this error "Could not cast value of type ViewController to MovieCell" with line let selectedItem = ...
Thanks for your time and effort
Here is my code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   
        if segue.identifier == "detailSegue"
            {
            let destination = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            let selectedItem = collectionView.indexPath(for: sender as! MovieCell)!
            let character = characters[selectedItem.item]
            destination.detailName = character.name
            destination.detailGender = character.gender
            destination.detailSpecies = character.species
            destination.detailStatus = character.status
            }
    
    }



override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {              
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)
   }
```

Comment: Have you created a segue directly from the cell in your storyboard?  If so, don't do that because that segue will fire before `didSelectItemAt` is called.

Comment: Unclear what the issue is. What data can you not pass?

Comment: I have created a segue from viewController @Paulw11

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints and using the very powerful Xcode debugger to see what is happening?  Your code could be very well falling through at the `if segue.identifier == ...`

Comment: I am parsing JSON and tried to pass name,gender,species,status of the data, however ,when I tap on cell I get "Could not cast calue of type "ViewController" to "MovieCell" @matt

Comment: That is very important information that you should include in your question - That means the segue isn't being invoked from `didSelectItemAt` - Your segue isn't set correctly in your storyboard.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes paul you are right, I set breakpoint at line if segue.identifier and it stopped execution (Sometimes I can't explain what the issue is because I am a beginner thanks for your comments)

Comment: That is what you expect with a breakpoint. You can then single step through your code and examine variables etc but the exception says that your `sender` Isn't a cell.

Comment: Could you give me an opinion where to look at in storyboard? Because I have checked it many times but I looks OK

Comment: Make sure that you have dragged from the view controller icon at the top of the scene to the destination scene to create your segue. Make sure that the only way that segue can be triggered is via `performSegue` in `didSelectItemAt`.

Comment: Checked but still get error when I tapped a cell , from let selectedItem =... line, (could not cast value of type error)anyways I will try to solve this issue. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try use:

```
    collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems.first
```

instead

```
    collectionView.indexPath(for: sender as! MovieCell)!
```

Also I wanna recommend for you my library for such situations: [Link](https://github.com/dhrebeniuk/SegueWithCompletion)